# Flutter Slider value not changing

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a Slider on a button press, which is working and when I print the variable for the value of the slider it's right. The TextEditingControllers change the value perfectly too, but the slider itself somehow doesn't move:

```
int liquidCounter = 1;

  List<TextEditingController> amountTextControllers = [
    new TextEditingController(),
    new TextEditingController(),
    new TextEditingController(),
    new TextEditingController(),
    new TextEditingController()
  ];

  List<Widget> widgetList = [];

  void addWidget(int index) {
    widgetList += [
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(44, 44, 44, 0.61)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Liquid ${index + 1}",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  isDense: true),
            ),
            Slider(
                value: _liquidSliderValues[index],
                max: 500,
                divisions: 100,
                label: _liquidSliderValues[index].toString() + " ml",
                onChanged: (double value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _liquidSliderValues[index] = value;
                    print(_liquidSliderValues[index]);
                    amountTextControllers[index].text = value.toString();
                  });
                }),
            TextFormField(
                controller: amountTextControllers[index],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _liquidSliderValues[index] = double.parse(value);
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Amount ml:")),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            DropdownMenu<int>(
                hintText: 'Container',
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                dropdownMenuEntries: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    .map<DropdownMenuEntry<int>>((int value) {
                  return DropdownMenuEntry<int>(
                      value: value, label: value.toString());
                }).toList()),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ];
    liquidCounter++;
  } //addWidget
```

I tried to just give one double instead of a list, which didn't change anything.
Also the set Slider, which is built from the beginning is working fine:

```
Slider(
                            value: _liquidSliderValues[0],
                            max: 500,
                            divisions: 100,
                            label: _liquidSliderValues[0].toString() + " ml",
                            onChanged: (double value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _liquidSliderValues[0] = value;
                                amountTextControllers[0].text =
                                    value.toString();
                              });
                            }),
```

Comment: Lots of things are wrong with your code. You should first try calling setState after calling the addWidget method. Please let me know if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Slider` widget is not reactive to the state changes because it's not inside the `build` method. It seems like you have a container list named `widgetList` that holds the widgets that are to be rendered in the `build` method. Refactor your code to actually have the `Slider` in the `build` method.

Change the `addWidget` method to something like this:

```dart
void addWidget(int index) {
  _liquidSliderValues.add(liquidCounter++);
}
```

And put the `Slider` widget in the `build` method with a for-in loop like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    for (final (index, sliderValue) in _liquidSliderValues.indexed)
      Slider(
        value: sliderValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _liquidSliderValues[index] = value;
          });
        },
        // ...
      ),
    // ...
  ],
),
```